# Geoserver unable to execute a PostGIS stored procedure

Tags: geoserver

I've a PostGIS stored procedure that does an insertion in a table, then it returns a value. Here it's:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO cities (id, name) VALUES (17, 'koko');
    RETURN 2;
END;
```

I was able to call the stored procedure from geoserver using "Configure new SQL view..." the view retuns the value correctly (which is 2), but no insertion is done in the DB.

What is the problem?

Comment: GeoServer probably (hopefully) sanitizes the view code to prevent people modifying the table

Comment: So the transaction is rolled-back, good to know (for all kind of injection isues). Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353286) for a workaround using dblink

Comment: So, there is no straight way to execute such stored function correctly from Geoserver?